# rbokeh color argument- legend messes up on R 3.6

Tags: rbokeh

The legend generated for an ly_bar figure that uses a variable for a color argument has a title of base::quote("variable_name"). This is only a problem when generating graphs on R 3.6.

```
figure() %>%
  ly_bar(variety, yield, color = year, data = lattice::barley, hover = TRUE) %>%
  theme_axis("x", major_label_orientation = 90)
```

The graph legend should say "year" instead of base::quote("year").